# How can I get my WCF Service constructor called?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I'm currently trying to get my head around WCF services for an ASP.NET dev environment, and I believe that I'm doing well save for one thing that has me stumped.

Basically, I've got a WCF service set up (let's take the default, with an added constructor):

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public MyService() { /* blah */ }
    public DoWork() { /* blah */ }
}
```

The `IMyService` interface defines the `DoWork()` method as an `[OperationContract]`, as it should.

So I've got this service referenced in another project (let's say a [Unit] Test Project), via *Add Service Reference* on the VS2010 UI. This creates a reference to a `MyServiceClient` which exposes my WCF service methods, as it should.

However, when I do this in my test project:

```
ServiceReference.IMyService service;
service = new ServiceReference.MyServiceClient();
```

... the `MyService()` constructor does not get called, basically because I'm instantiating a `MyServiceClient`, not a `MyService` per se.

How do I go about getting that constructor called? I'm planning to use that for initialization purposes (perhaps grabbing a layer in a tiered implementation, for example?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That constructor will be called on the *server* when you make your request from the client.

Creating a "reference" to a web service (and then using the client classes) is very different to referencing a regular .DLL.  All of your service code will run on the server-side, but not until the service is invoked...

Comment: So basically, you're saying that instead of _Add Service Reference_, I should just go with a good ol' _Add Reference_ to the service project, then accessing the service classes directly?

Comment: No, adding a service reference is correct... but the constructor in your service class doesn't run as part of your local code - it runs on your IIS server when you *call* the service.  It *will* get called before any of your service methods run, just not when you create your client object.

Comment: Gotcha. Was working through with your solution when I realized that I haven't actually called any service methods in my test project just yet. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way for the server-side constructor to be called for each request is to set the InstanceContextMode to PerCall (in the ServiceBehavior attribute).

Comment: That's right, but I think you mean the ServiceBehavior attribute. :)